# Trinomial trees in LaTex

Tags: tikz-trees

I'm trying to draw a specific trinomial tree in LaTex, the tree is taken from Hull's book, Options, futures and other derivatives. [image]

Comment: Welcome. // What is your question?

Answer (score 5):

While it might look like a tree it looks much easier to be drawn with the [`tikz-cd` package](https://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-cd) as it places all nodes (here the black dots) in a grid-like manner, a [matrix](https://tikz.dev/tikz-matrices).

Connecting the dots can be done with the `\arrow` syntax of TikZ-CD, here via the shortcuts `\rar`, `\urar` and `\drar` which stand for `\arrow[r]`, `\arrow[ur]` and `\arrow[dr]` (i.e. an arrow to the *r*ight, *u*p and to the *r*ight as well as one *d*own and to the *r*ight).

The actual text will be placed by the way of [labels](https://tikz.dev/tikz-shapes#pgf.label).

The arrow tips along the lines are placed via the undocumented `\pgfarrowdraw` in a pic called *arrow*. For more variety and control over the placement of arrow tips along a path, take a look at the [library `decorations.markings`](https://tikz.dev/library-decorations#sec-50.6.1).

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\tikzset{
  pics/arrow/.style={/tikz/sloped, /tikz/allow upside down,
    code=\pgfarrowdraw{#1}}, pics/arrow/.default=>}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[
  dot/.style={circle, fill, draw, inner sep=+0pt, minimum size=+3.5pt,
    /utils/exec=\ifnum\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn<4 \rar\urar\drar\fi},
  /tikz/d/.style ={commutative diagrams/dot, label={above:{#1}}},
  /tikz/d</.style={commutative diagrams/dot, label={ left:{#1}}},
  /tikz/d>/.style={commutative diagrams/dot, label={right:{#1}}},
  arrows={-, /tikz/every to/.append style={
    edge node={pic[pos=.95]{arrow=Stealth}}}},
  column sep={3cm,between origins}, row sep={1.33cm,between origins},
]
             &             &               & |[d>=S_0 u^3]| \\
             &             & |[d=S_0 u^2]| & |[d>=S_0 u^2]| \\
             & |[d=S_0 u]| & |[d=S_0 u  ]| & |[d>=S_0 u  ]| \\
  |[d<=S_0]| & |[d=S_0  ]| & |[d=S_0    ]| & |[d>=S_0    ]| \\
             & |[d=S_0 d]| & |[d=S_0 d  ]| & |[d>=S_0 d  ]| \\
             &             & |[d=S_0 d^2]| & |[d>=S_0 d^2]| \\
             &             &               & |[d>=S_0 d^3]|
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help, really appreciate it