# 3D blocks and flow diagrams

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, tikz-styles

This is second attempt to reproduce the diagram below. [image]

It was recommended that I use `fit` library, I tried it out and I got to the point below:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

%% Language and font encodings
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usetikzlibrary {fit}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{darkblue}{HTML}{1f4e79}
\definecolor{lightblue}{HTML}{00b0f0}
\definecolor{salmon}{HTML}{ff9c6b}

\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,calc,shadings,shapes.arrows,arrows,shapes.symbols,shadows,positioning,decorations.markings,backgrounds,arrows.meta}

% Define parallelepiped shape:
\makeatletter
\pgfkeys{/pgf/.cd,
  parallelepiped offset x/.initial=2mm,
  parallelepiped offset y/.initial=2mm
}
\pgfdeclareshape{parallelepiped}
{
  \inheritsavedanchors[from=rectangle] % this is nearly a rectangle
  \inheritanchorborder[from=rectangle]
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north west}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north east}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{center}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{west}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{east}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{mid}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{mid west}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{mid east}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{base}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{base west}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{base east}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south west}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south east}
  \backgroundpath{
    % store lower right in xa/ya and upper right in xb/yb
    \southwest \pgf@xa=\pgf@x \pgf@ya=\pgf@y
    \northeast \pgf@xb=\pgf@x \pgf@yb=\pgf@y
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgfutil@tempdima{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/parallelepiped
      offset x}}
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgfutil@tempdimb{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/parallelepiped
      offset y}}
    \def\ppd@offset{\pgfpoint{\pgfutil@tempdima}{\pgfutil@tempdimb}}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@ya}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@ya}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yb}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@yb}}
    \pgfpathclose
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@ya}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointadd{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@ya}}{\ppd@offset}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointadd{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yb}}{\ppd@offset}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointadd{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@yb}}{\ppd@offset}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@yb}}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yb}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointadd{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yb}}{\ppd@offset}}
  }
}
\makeatother

\tikzset{
  % Dark blue blocks
  block/.style={
    parallelepiped,fill=white, draw,
    minimum width=0.2cm,
    minimum height=3.2cm,
    parallelepiped offset x=0.5cm,
    parallelepiped offset y=0.5cm,
    path picture={
      \draw[top color=darkblue,bottom color=darkblue]
        (path picture bounding box.south west) rectangle 
        (path picture bounding box.north east);
    },
    text=white,
  },
  % many
   block2/.style={
    parallelepiped,fill=white, draw,
    minimum width=0.3cm,
    minimum height=2.7cm,
    parallelepiped offset x=0.5cm,
    parallelepiped offset y=0.5cm,
    path picture={
      \draw[top color=darkblue,bottom color=darkblue]
        (path picture bounding box.south west) rectangle 
        (path picture bounding box.north east);
    },
    text=white,
  },
  %last
    block3/.style={
    parallelepiped,fill=white, draw,
    minimum width=0.3cm,
    minimum height=1.7cm,
    parallelepiped offset x=0.5cm,
    parallelepiped offset y=0.5cm,
    path picture={
      \draw[top color=darkblue,bottom color=darkblue]
        (path picture bounding box.south west) rectangle 
        (path picture bounding box.north east);
    },
    text=white,
  },
 % Orange-ish blocks
  conv/.style={
    parallelepiped,fill=white, draw,
    minimum width=0.8cm,
    minimum height=1.0cm,
    parallelepiped offset x=0.1cm,
    parallelepiped offset y=0.1cm,
    path picture={
      \draw[top color=salmon,bottom color=salmon]
        (path picture bounding box.south west) rectangle 
        (path picture bounding box.north east);
    },
    text=white,
  },
  % Orange-ish blocks
  conv2/.style={
    parallelepiped,fill=white, draw,
    minimum width=0.4cm,
    minimum height=1.0cm,
    parallelepiped offset x=0.5cm,
    parallelepiped offset y=0.5cm,
    path picture={
      \draw[top color=salmon,bottom color=salmon]
        (path picture bounding box.south west) rectangle 
        (path picture bounding box.north east);
    },
    text=white,
  },
  % Taller Light blue blocks:
  plate/.style={
    parallelepiped,fill=white, draw,
    minimum width=0.09cm,
    minimum height=3.1cm,
    parallelepiped offset x=0.5cm,
    parallelepiped offset y=0.5cm,
    path picture={
      \draw[top color=lightblue,bottom color=lightblue]
        (path picture bounding box.south west) rectangle 
        (path picture bounding box.north east);
    },
    text=white,
  },
  % style
   % Taller Light blue blocks:
  plate2/.style={
    parallelepiped,fill=white, draw,
    minimum width=0.1cm,
    minimum height=2.5cm,
    parallelepiped offset x=0.5cm,
    parallelepiped offset y=0.5cm,
    path picture={
      \draw[top color=lightblue,bottom color=lightblue]
        (path picture bounding box.south west) rectangle 
        (path picture bounding box.north east);
    },
    text=white,
  },
  % Arrows between blocks:
  link/.style={
    color=white,
    line width=1mm,
  },
  link2/.style={
    color=lightblue,
    line width=1mm,
  },
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  % The order of blocks matters since some are partially hidden behind subsequent blocks.

  \node[conv](conv1) {\rotatebox{90}{Train Data}};
   
 \node[conv, above=0.9cm of conv1 ](conv3) 
  {\rotatebox{90}{Generator}};
    \node[conv, below=0.9cm of conv1 ](conv2) 
  {\rotatebox{90}{Ref. Data }};
  
  % \node[plate,right=4.9cm of conv1](plate1){};
  % yshift to align the bottom of that blocks with the previous taller block.
  \node[block,right=3.cm of conv1,yshift=0.001cm](resblock1){\rotatebox{90}{1}};

    \draw [-triangle 60,link2] ([xshift=0.1cm,yshift=0.2cm]conv1.east) -- ([xshift=0.0cm,yshift=0.2cm]resblock1.west);
  
  \node[block,right=0.1cm of resblock1](resblock2){\rotatebox{90}{1}};
  
  % \node[block,above=0.1cm of resblock1](resblock2){\rotatebox{90}{2}};
  % \node[block,above=0.1cm of resblock2](resblock3){\rotatebox{90}{3}};
  % \node[block,right=0.2cm of resblock1](x1){\rotatebox{90}{(X4)}};
  % \node[block,above=0.1cm of x1](x2){\rotatebox{90}{Dense Layer}};
  % \node[block,above=0.1cm of x2](x3){\rotatebox{90}{(X2)}};
  \node[plate,right=0.2cm of resblock2](plate2){\rotatebox{90}{BatchNorm}};
  \node[block2,right=0.2cm of plate2](resblock4){\rotatebox{90}{ResBlock4}};
  \node[block2,right=0.1cm of resblock4](resblock6){\rotatebox{90}{ResBlock6}};

\node[plate2,right=0.2cm of resblock6](plate3){\rotatebox{90}{\small BatchNorm}};;

  \node[block3,right=0.3cm of plate3](resblock5){\rotatebox{90}{ \small
 ResBlock5}};
 
  
  \node[conv2,right=0.2cm of resblock5](last){\rotatebox{90}{Conv}};
   \node[draw=red,very thick,   fit=(resblock1) (resblock1) (plate2) (resblock4) (resblock4) (plate3) (resblock5) (last)  ](fitter) {};
  % \draw [-,link] ([xshift=0.2cm,yshift=0.2cm]last.east) -- ([yshift=0.2cm]last.west);
% \node[below] at (fit.south) {box};
 \node[above] at (fitter.south) {box};
  \node[below] at (fitter.north) {box};
\draw [link] ([xshift=1.cm,yshift=0.2cm]last.east) -- ([xshift=1.5cm,yshift=0.2cm]last.east) ;

\draw [-triangle 60,link2] ([xshift=0.1cm,yshift=0.2cm]fitter.west) -- ([xshift=0.0cm,yshift=0.2cm]conv3.east);

\draw [-triangle 60,link2] ([xshift=0.0cm,yshift=0.0cm]conv3.south) -- ([xshift=0.0cm,yshift=0.0cm]conv1.north);

\draw [-triangle 60,link2] ([xshift=0.0cm,yshift=0.0cm]conv2.north) -- ([xshift=0.0cm,yshift=0.0cm]conv1.south);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This was inspired by the solution here [Producing stacked 3D blocks using TikZ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50131068/producing-stacked-3d-blocks-using-tikz) and the recommendation from the solution here [Flow diagam and 3D diagrams tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/681938/flow-diagam-and-3d-diagrams-tikz) .

The output I have now is as below:

[image]

I want to :

1. add the arrows properly and format the fit the rectangle appropriately
2. add the text accordingly.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you use the `path picture` option and not just `fill` the shapes? You can try `right=0.1cm of resblock1.south east, anchor=south west` to align the blocks at the bottom.

Comment: As for the `fit` problem, you can always either use anchors (if they exist) or `xshift`/`yshift` as options to the coordinates you want to fit (like `([yshift=1cm]resblock1)` for example), to correctly fit the node. Note that you need to place the argument to the `fit` option inside curly braces (`{}`) if you want to use square brackets (`[]`) inside.

Comment: @JasperHabicht I appreciate the feedback. I will work on the recommendations accordingly.

Comment: The `fit` library only takes the main compass anchors (north, east, south and west) in consideration when you just give it a node name. The shape's definition doesn't change any of these anchors from the original rectangle which is why the 3d-ness of that shape is basically invisible for `fit`. There's room for improvement in that shape's definition. As a workaround you could have those cuboids create coordinates automatically on-the-fly and use them in `fit` to avoid having to use `[yshift=1cm]` like @JasperHabicht suggested.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel True, `yshift` should probably only be used together with coordinates in the context of `fit`. I just suggested it as another option which I though might be easier for the OP then to redefine the shape.

Comment: Why did you tag it `circuitikz`? I do not see where I can help here...

Comment: @Rmano that was my mistake. I have removed the tag accordingly. Thank you for the observation.

Comment: @koolaids thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I've condensed your styles down to a few:

   - a common `block` with the most commen settings (shape and its offset, `draw` and `text = white`),
   - `plate` that is the same as block but the `fill` color is `lightblue` instead of `darkblue`,
   - `conv` that are the thinner (→ smaller offset) orange blocks.

   Then, they are the three sizes: `size 1`, `size 2`and `size 3`.
2. Instead of placing all those nodes inside the `fit` box manually, I'm using the `chains` library with the custom `bottom right` placement rule which makes the nodes bottom-aligned.

   This rule is set by using `start chain = going bottom right` and then placing each node `on chain`.
3. We can now use two nested `\foreach` loops to place the nodes, the outer loop determines its size by its own counter `\CNT` and the inner loop goes through each size group and actually places the `\node`s with the appropriate `\STYLE`.
4. While the `chains` library implicitly gives aliases to the nodes, we still need to give them manually explicit names so that we can actually use the effects of the `every parallelepiped node` style which places a coordinate at the (real) upper right corner of your boxes. (It'd be better to improve the shape and add real anchors but that'll do for now.)
5. In the value for the `fit` key we not only use the bare name of the first node `gr1-1` but also these coordinates `gr1-1-North East` and `gr3-2-North East` of which we know that they encompass everything.
6. With `outer sep` set to zero we can now use the four sides of the rectangle to add text, arrows and a coordinate `box-ne` for later.
7. The tree boxes on the left gets added.
8. All edges get drawn.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\definecolor{darkblue}{HTML}{1f4e79}
\definecolor{lightblue}{HTML}{00b0f0}
\definecolor{salmon}{HTML}{ff9c6b}
\definecolor{buff}{RGB}{218, 160, 109}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds, chains, fit, positioning, arrows.meta, quotes}
% Define parallelepiped shape:
\pgfset{
  parallelepiped offset x/.initial=2mm,
  parallelepiped offset y/.initial=2mm}
\makeatletter
\pgfdeclareshape{parallelepiped}{%
  \inheritsavedanchors[from=rectangle] % this is nearly a rectangle
  \inheritanchorborder[from=rectangle]
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north west}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north east}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{center}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{west}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{east}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{mid}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{mid west}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{mid east}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{base}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{base west}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{base east}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south west}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south east}
  \backgroundpath{%
    % store lower right in xa/ya and upper right in xb/yb
    \southwest \pgf@xa=\pgf@x \pgf@ya=\pgf@y
    \northeast \pgf@xb=\pgf@x \pgf@yb=\pgf@y
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgfutil@tempdima{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/parallelepiped offset x}}%
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgfutil@tempdimb{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/parallelepiped offset y}}%
    \def\ppd@offset{\pgfpoint{\pgfutil@tempdima}{\pgfutil@tempdimb}}%
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@ya}}%
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@ya}}%
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yb}}%
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@yb}}%
    \pgfpathclose
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@ya}}%
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointadd{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@ya}}{\ppd@offset}}%
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointadd{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yb}}{\ppd@offset}}%
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointadd{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@yb}}{\ppd@offset}}%
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@yb}}%
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yb}}%
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointadd{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yb}}{\ppd@offset}}%
  }
}
\makeatother

\tikzset{
  block/.style={
    shape=parallelepiped,
    fill=darkblue, draw, text=white,
    parallelepiped offset x=0.5cm,
    parallelepiped offset y=0.5cm},
  size 1/.style={minimum width=0.2cm, minimum height=3.2cm},
  size 2/.style={minimum width=0.3cm, minimum height=2.7cm},
  size 3/.style={minimum width=0.3cm, minimum height=1.7cm},
 % Orange-ish blocks
  conv/.style={block, minimum width=0.8cm, minimum height=1.0cm,
    fill=salmon, parallelepiped offset x=0.1cm, parallelepiped offset y=0.1cm},
  % Taller Light blue blocks:
  plate/.style={block, fill=lightblue},
}
\tikzset{% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/674354/16595
  pics/arrow/.style={/tikz/sloped, /tikz/allow upside down,
    code=\pgfarrowdraw{#1}}, pics/arrow/.default=>,
  every parallelepiped node/.style={
    label/.expanded={[shape=coordinate,name=\noexpand\tikzlastnode-North East,
      xshift={\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/parallelepiped offset x}},
      yshift={\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/parallelepiped offset y}}]north east:}},
  bottom right/.style={right=#1.south east, anchor=south west}}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  > = {Triangle[angle'=45, scale=.5]},
  |-/.style={to path=|-(\tikztotarget)\tikztonodes}
]
\newcommand*\rot[1]{\rotatebox{90}{#1}}
\begin{scope}[start chain=going bottom right, node distance=2mm]
\foreach[count=\CNT] \GROUP in {
  {block/1,         block/1,         plate/BatchNorm},
  {block/ResBlock4, block/ResBlock6, plate/BatchNorm},
  {block/ResBlock5,                  conv/Conv}}
  \foreach[count=\CCNT] \STYLE/\TEXT in \GROUP
    \node[on chain, size \CNT/.try, \STYLE] (gr\CNT-\CCNT) {\rot{\TEXT}};
\end{scope}

\tikzset{line width=1mm}
\node[
  fit=(gr1-1)(gr1-1-North East)(gr3-2-North East),
  rounded corners=+5mm, draw,
  inner sep=+8mm, outer sep=+0pt] (box) {};
\path[pos=.6] (box.north east) -- node[below, buff] {Some text, some text}
                                  pic               {arrow}
                                  coordinate[pos=.2] (box-ne) (box.north west);
\path[at end, every pic/.append style={xshift=-5mm}]
  (box.north west) -- pic{arrow} (box.south west)
  (box.south east) -- pic{arrow} (box.north east);

\tikzset{node distance=.9cm and 2cm}
\node[conv, left =of box      ] (trainData) {\rot{Train Data}};
\node[conv, above=of trainData] (generator) {\rot{Generator}};
\node[conv, below=of trainData] (refData)   {\rot{Ref. Data}};

\path[->] (generator) edge (trainData)
          (refData)   edge (trainData)
 [nodes=buff]
          (box-ne)    edge[|-, "Some text"' near end] (generator)
          (trainData) edge[buff!50!black, shorten >=2mm, shorten <=2mm,
                           "Text", "Text"'] (box)
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Awesome! Now I have a lot to learn from this.

Comment: @koolaids No problems. It's probably not the perfect solution to what you're trying to achieve but maybe it gets you farther on the way. Don't forget that there's also the `decoration.markings` library that can place arrow tips along paths. It provides more functionality but or many instances my `arrow` pic is much easier to handle, in my opinion.