# Fitting text into a 3d shape in tikz using \draw and \node

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to make a 3d colored box with text in it.

So far, I have this long code below:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows, positioning,3d}

\begin{document}


\begin{frame}[t]{Why is it important?}

\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,scale=3]
    \coordinate (A1) at (0, 0);
    \coordinate (A2) at (0, 0.5);
    \coordinate (A3) at (2, 0.5);
    \coordinate (A4) at (2, 0);
    %\coordinate (B1) at (0.3, 0.3);
    \coordinate (B2) at (0.1, 0.6);
    \coordinate (B3) at (2.1, 0.6);
    \coordinate (B4) at (2.1, 0.1);

    \draw[very thick] (A1) -- (A2);
    \draw[very thick] (A2) -- (A3);
    \draw[very thick] (A3) -- (A4);
    \draw[very thick] (A4) -- (A1);

    \draw[very thick] (A2) -- (B2);
    \draw[very thick] (B2) -- (B3);
    \draw[very thick] (A3) -- (B3);
    \draw[very thick] (A4) -- (B4);
    \draw[very thick] (B4) -- (B3);


    \draw[fill=black!20,opacity=0.5] (A1) -- (A2) -- (A3) -- (A4);
    \draw[fill=blue,opacity=0.6] (A3) -- (B3) -- (B4) -- (A4);
    \draw[fill=green,opacity=0.6] (A2) -- (B2) -- (B3) -- (A3);
    \node[anchor=center,xshift=1.15in,yshift=0.255in]{{\Large\fontspec{QTFuture} New research questions!}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, I could only fit the text `{\Large\fontspec{QTFuture} New research questions!}` and box manually so that it fits somewhat into the front grey area `\draw[fill=black!20,opacity=0.5]`.

Is there another way of fitting the text perfectly into the front gray area.

Maybe there is another tikz method i.e. `\node` that can make a 3d textbox.

The screenshots look like this:
[image: Entire slide]

[image: Textbox]

Comment: Can you please add a screenshot? Thank you

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but no need for `\usepackage{xcolor}`, beamer already loads this for you

Comment: Best would be to adjust [this parallelepiped](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/681970) to have three paths (so they can be colored independetly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could draw the text in a node and then add the sides based on the corners of the node:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
%\usepackage{fontspec}
%\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,scale=3,line join=bevel]
    \node[fill=black!10,inner sep=0.5cm,draw=black] (foo) {{\Large New research questions!}};
    \fill[blue!40,draw=black] (foo.south east) -- ++(0.15cm,0.15cm) -- ($(foo.north east)+(0.15cm,0.15cm)$) -- (foo.north east) -- cycle;
    \fill[green!40,draw=black] (foo.north west) -- ++(0.15cm,0.15cm) -- ($(foo.north east)+(0.15cm,0.15cm)$) -- (foo.north east) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\vfill

\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,scale=3,line join=bevel]
    \node[fill=black!10,inner sep=0.5cm,draw=black] (foo) {{\Large Quack!}};
    \fill[blue!40,draw=black] (foo.south east) -- ++(0.15cm,0.15cm) -- ($(foo.north east)+(0.15cm,0.15cm)$) -- (foo.north east) -- cycle;
    \fill[green!40,draw=black] (foo.north west) -- ++(0.15cm,0.15cm) -- ($(foo.north east)+(0.15cm,0.15cm)$) -- (foo.north east) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]